# idiom for mapping multiple "arguments" to single variadic parameter

Tags: go

Is there a way to use a combination of splatted arguments and simple arguments (defined below) in a function taking a variadic parameter in golang? If not, is there a well-known idiom that approximates this feature? If possible, is there an idiom approximating this feature that does not require repeating the type name?

---

Suppose I have a function with a variadic parameter in golang of type `...T`.
It seems like your options at the call site are limited to:

- multiple *simple arguments*, each of type `T`, i.e. `f(…… x1, x2, x3 ……)`
- a single *splatted argument* of type `[]T`, i.e `f(…… ...xs ……)`

In some other languages like Python, it is possible to *capture* a combination of simple arguments and splatted arguments with a variadic parameter:

```
$ python
>>> def foo(*args): return args
... 
>>> foo(1, 2, *[3, 4])
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

However, the same thing does not appear to work in go.

```
// splat.go
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"

func write(args ...string) {
        for _, item := range args {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", item)
        }
}

func main() {
        write("foobarbaz", os.Args[1:]...)
}
```

from the error message, it's clear that the splatted argument and the simple argument are not being mapped to the same parameter.

```
$ go run splat.go 
# command-line-arguments
./splat.go:14: too many arguments in call to write
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a slice with all of the arguments and splat that slice.

```
write(append([]string{"foobarbaz"}, os.Args[1:]...)...)
```

If the `string, []string` pattern is common in the application code, then consider writing a function to simplify the code at the call sites:

```
func stringArgs(s string, args []string) []string { 
   return append([]string{s}, args...)
}

...

write(stringArgs("foobarbaz", os.Args[1:])...)
```

or

```
func writeStringArgs(s string, args []string) {
    write(append([]string{"foobarbaz"}, os.Args[1:]...)...)
}

...

writeStringArgs(s, os.Args[1:])
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this that does not require repeating the type name (`[]string{……}`)?

Comment: interface{} is the catch-all generic type in go - but will only work if the target function accepts this generic type explicitly. I think you are angling for Generics - which go 1.X does not support. go 2.X may support generics, but that's a long way away.

Comment: @colminator ... go doesn't have first class or user-definable generics, but it does have certain built-in things like `range` and `append` that behave like polymorphic functions. It seems as though prepending to a slice is not possible without naming the type in question.

Comment: You certainly can achieve what you want as long as the root type is interface{}. See the reflect package. But to reiterate my earlier comment, your target function *must* accept an interface{} type to achieve any generic behavior.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet There is not a way to create the slice without mentioning a type.